# QGIS @parent or import to database(Error 7) not working for layer

Tags: qgis, layers, spatialite

I have a shape file layer that won't load into the SpatiaLite database and it gives Error 7.  It also won't run functions that work in other layers and works fine without the @parent or if I remove the filter.

```
> aggregate ( 'Mainland_Address_079da3c1_0048_4cf5_ba0d_e89a4d130688',
>              'concatenate', 
>              to_string("CIVICNUM"),
>              filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) , 
>              concatenator:=' ,')
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with it.  Unfortunately I can't share it  because it has sensitive information. But I can share the Information and Source Fields.  My project is using EPSG:4326. What is the issue with the layer? [image: Information] [image: Source Fields]

Edit: Error 7 Picture

[image: Error 7]

Edit: Table picture

[image: Table]

Comment: Is there more information provided in the error message, or does it only say "error 7"? Have you tried to look up what "error 7" means? Please [edit] this information into your question.

Comment: I've looked into Error 7 and found a few items that were 2 years old but didn't seem related anymore as the issues were fixed.  I also noticed it created a table for the level but there isn't any informative.  It is just a blank table.  See next picture attached.